# User Name is invalid. unable to read the username from database(ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

i was trying to create a login page that connected to my database. but it showed user is invalid. May i know what is the problem? thanks!
here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ToString());
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = " select count(*) from [Table] where UserName = ' " + TextBoxUserName.Text + "' and Password='"+ TextBoxPassword.Text + "' ";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            Session["user"] = TextBoxUserName.Text;
            Response.Write("Login success");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Login fail");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a session called `user`? Can you provide us with the full error message?

Comment: Are the users stored in `[Table]` or is this just a placeholder in your example code? As a side node, never concatenate user inputs to SQL queries directly, instead use `SqlParameter` to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) (e.g. I could send TextBoxPassword as `; DROP TABLE [Table];`)

Comment: PS: You also seem to store the passwords as plain text in the DB? It would be more secure to use the built-in [ASP Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) for login instead of a home-grown solution...

Answer (score 1):

To your question first: You have a space, where you shouldn't have one.
 `where UserName = ' "`  
The system checks this space too and that's wrong. You only want the TextBox Content, am I right.

The second thing is the security of this code. Your code is very vulnerable to sql injections and the password should never be in plain Text, **Hash** is the better answer.